# Custom post edit with button to save post and start creating new

Tags: autosave

I have custom post edit screen with custom metaboxes and wanted the last metabox to "Save this post and start creating a new one".

It's easy to redirect user to new post creation page with url like post-new.php?post_type=customposttype
but what url should I call with javascript before this to make the post saved?

Thanks

```php
    add_meta_box("addanotheritem", 'Add another', 'addanother_metabox', 'custompost', 'side', 'high'); 

        
    function addanother_metabox() {  
    
    ?>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
         function saveAndGo() {  
            jQuery('button.editor-post-publish-button__button').click();  
            window.location='./post-new.php?post_type=custompost';  
            return false;  
         }  
        </script>  
        <button onclick='javascript:saveAndGo();'>save & add another</button>  
        <?php  
    }
```

Comment: perhaps bind a click event to the editor save button?

Comment: that would be great, how this can be done?

Comment: Perhaps search for triggering click via javascript - in vanilla it would be something like - document.querySelector("#BUTTON_ID").click();

Comment: This question has some good examples - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347512/fake-click-to-activate-an-onclick-method - then you need to find the ID of the element you want to "click"..

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. It still asks if you want do drop changes even though save button is clicked prior to redirect.

Comment: Share the code you use, then people can offer more than concepts, they can see the code and offer definitive answers.

Comment: ```add_meta_box("addanotheritem", 'Add another', 'addanother_metabox', 'custompost', 'side', 'high');  
  
    function addanother_metabox() {  
  $urlNew="./post-new.php?post_type=custompost";  
  ?>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
   function saveAndGo() {  
   jQuery('input.editor-post-publish-button__button').click();  
   window.location=<?= "'".$urlNew."'"?>;  
   return false;  
   }  
  </script>  
  <button onclick='javascript:saveAndGo();'>save & go</button>  
  <a href='<?= $urlNew?>'>Add another</a>  
  <?php  
 }```

Comment: Please update your question, code in comments is not readable - you can edit your own question.

Comment: sorry, I have already updated the question

Comment: You are probably going to need to implement a "promise" or check that the post is saved and then redirect once that is complete, to overcome the error.

Comment: need to study about promises, but I got the solution, I used "stupid" timeout and it works

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda stupid solution, but 2s timeout is acceptable solution

```
 add_meta_box("addanotheritem", 'Add another', 'addanother_metabox', 'custompost', 'side', 'high'); 

        
    function addanother_metabox() {  
    
    ?>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
         function saveAndGo() {  
            jQuery('button.editor-post-publish-button__button').click();  
            setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location='./post-new.php?post_type=custompost';
                    }, 2000);   
            return false;  
         }  
        </script>  
        <button onclick='javascript:saveAndGo();'>save & add another</button>  
        <?php  
    }
```